# why pipeline is still is in running state even after test case has been passed in testing stage?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

why pipeline is still is in running state even after test case has been passed in testing stage?
I am running a selenium C# test case in testing stage on pipeline using dotnet test, and generating an html report for that test case.
So on pipeline build stage is getting passed and at testing stage: test case is running fine and generating html report but pipeline is still in running state.
How to make the pipeline pass after test case is getting passed?

I have tried changing the timeout for runner job in settings.
But after completing the timeout time, pipeline is failing even after test case getting passed.

Comment: Can you try after the dotnet test command to add || exit

Comment: Can you tell me the better way to include exit or add in yml file? I have used this command after dotnet test:  "exit 128 || true"   but now test cases are not executing and  test results are not generating , although testing stage is now getting passed.

Comment: I'm not sure what exit 128 do in your case but can you separate it ? dotnet test || exit. The "exit" is to terminate the shell. If "dotnet test" command fails, the shell will exit and not continue.

Comment: I have used :   'dotnet test  "path for dll file which has been built in gitlab runner folder in the build stage "  --filter Name=TestName --logger:html || exit' .    In this case, testcase in not running and html report is not generated. It is only getting exit with testing stage getting passed.        If I run it without exit, then test case is running and html report is generated and after that testing stage is in running state for timeout duration and then getting failed.                                                                        Is there anything I need to change?